# How to self study a topic for the second time?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, self-learning

So here is a bit of context: a while back (June-July), I studied a little bit of Abstract Algebra from an introductory book. Now, I would like to study more, in a complete fashion, using Herstein's book "Topics in Algebra". But I don't really know how to do it.

The first time around, I followed my usual self-study routine: write down definitions, theorems and some examples, and, in between, try to explain to myself the meaning of some things, as I would if I had to teach someone who has never seen it before. After that, I would do some exercises (mostly the harder ones) and move on to the next chapter. This routine worked really well for me whenever I used it, and I seem to remember a lot (not very surprising, since I am pretty much mimicking what I'd do on a formal class).

However, now will be my **second** time seeing many concepts and I feel like writing everything down again will be sort of... unnecessary? I have never done this before, studying something only to study the same thing again but deeper, so I have no idea how to adapt my study routine to this case...

I know it is a very personal subject, but do you guys have any tips? Have you ever been through this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: include other texts, other books of higher level and compare

Comment: Even if you don’t write the definitions down, I would say that it is a good idea to at least read the first chapter. Terminology can sometimes be slightly different as well as notation. Besides the first chapter, I would still do something similar to your initial self-study of abstract algebra (and depending on how the first chapter is presented, possibly even for this chapter). As for exercises, don’t think you need to do all of them, but I recommend not exclusively focusing on only the ones that seem hard, either. The more basic ones help develop intuition and a feel for the theory.

Comment: @Clayton Thanks for the comment! I read the first chapter in a "light" fashion, just to see the notation and preliminary definitions. Regarding the rest, what about overlaps? For example, preliminary theorems or definitions of basic concepts, such as groups, rings, etc? What do you recommend I do on that case? One final note: what I actually do regarding exercises is to try and solve the ones that interest me + the ones I don't know how to solve (I.E., I skip the ones that I can work out in my head just by looking).

Comment: EDIT: By "overlaps", I mean "things I have seen before"

Comment: For topics that you’ve already read about or touched on in another book, I would read these sections in the same “light” fashion unless there were new things included as part of the presentation. If there are new things, I’d write it out.

Comment: @Clayton Thank you so much!